# Add String Between Two Parts of Text

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I've just implemented the ability to post to Facebook. I want to post the highscore to Facebook like this. "My New Highscore on game is" *highscore* "Try to beat it" but how do I put the second piece of text? Since trying to add the "Try to beat it", it doesn't work
This is my code

```
NSString *nssHighscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", highscore];

mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"My New Highscore is" nssHighscore @"Try Beat it"];

[self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode (removed tag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My New Highscore is %@ Try Beat it", nssHighscore]];
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It's exactly what I was after. Although there needs to be one more square bracket ] at the end. Any idea how to do a line break?

Comment: May be it's: @"line1 \n line2"

Answer (score 2):

I guess your code doesn't compile... This isn't valid:

```
@"My New Highscore is" nssHighscore @"Try Beat it"
```

You need to create a string using a format, you already have something close you just need to use the format better:

```
NSString *nssHighscore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My New Highscore is %i. Try Beat it", highscore];
```

Then use the string directly:

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:nssHighscore];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My New Highscore is %d - Try to Beat it!", highscore];
```

Considering that `highscore` is an int